# Построение запроса SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть три таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id               INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('global_seq'),
  name             VARCHAR                 NOT NULL,
  enabled          BOOL DEFAULT TRUE       NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('global_seq'),
  user_id       INTEGER        NOT NULL,
  status        VARCHAR        NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE order_details (
  id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('global_seq'),
  amount     NUMERIC(13, 2) NOT NULL,
  order_id   INTEGER        NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Как видите `ORDERS` имеет связь с `USERS`, и `ORDER_DETAILS` имеет связь c `ORDERS`.

Как можно получить все `ORDER_DETAILS` по известному `user_id` из `ORDERS`, и известному `order_id` из `ORDER_DETAILS`? Надо обязательно искать по двум параметрах, по `user_id` и `order_id`, нужна максимальная проверка.

```
SELECT s.id, s.fuel_name, s.quantity FROM order_details s
RIGHT join orders q ON s.order_id =100004 WHERE q.user_id=100000
```

Такой запрос ни к чему не приводит. Когда меняю `user_id` возвращается место ничего, все записи.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from orders, order_details where orders.id=order_details.order_id and user_id=1
```

Comment: Мне запрос нужен( Если бы я знал как запрос построить и вопросов бы не было

Comment: SELECT s.id, s.fuel_name, s.quantity FROM order_details s
RIGHT join orders q ON s.order_id =100004 WHERE q.user_id=100000 AND q.id =100004

Comment: Но ваш походу лучше)

Comment: Запрос не правильный. Таблицы объединяются. И когда я пытаюсь выбрать конкретные колонки нужны альясы. и когда я их объявляю, то PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "orders"

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users
> (
>   id               INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
>   name             VARCHAR                 NOT NULL,
>   enabled          BOOL DEFAULT TRUE       NOT NULL
> );
> CREATE TABLE orders (
>   id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
>   user_id       INTEGER        NOT NULL,
>   status        VARCHAR        NOT NULL,
>   FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
> );
> CREATE TABLE order_details (
>   id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
>   amount     NUMERIC(13, 2) NOT NULL,
>   order_id   INTEGER        NOT NULL,
>   FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into users (id, name, enabled) values
> (1, 'Пользователь 1', true),
> (2, 'Пользователь 2', true);
> ```

> ```
> insert into orders (id, user_id, status) values
> (1, 1, 'Draft'),
> (2, 1, 'Ok'),
> (3, 1, 'Draft'),
> (4, 2, 'Draft'),
> (5, 2, 'Ok');
> ```

> ```
> insert into order_details (id, order_id, amount) values
> ( 1, 1, 10),
> ( 2, 1, 11),
> ( 3, 1, 12),
> ( 4, 1, 13),
> ( 5, 1, 14),
> ( 6, 2, 20),
> ( 7, 2, 21),
> ( 8, 2, 22),
> ( 9, 2, 23),
> (10, 3, 30),
> (11, 3, 31),
> (12, 4, 40),
> (13, 4, 41),
> (14, 5, 50);
> ```

> ```
> select
>    o.id          orders__ID,
>    o.user_id     orders__USER_ID,
>    o.status      orders__STATUS,
>    od.order_id   order_details__ID,
>    od.id         order_details__ORDER_ID,
>    od.amount     order_details__AMOUNT
> from orders o
>   join order_details od on o.id = od.order_id
> where 
>    o.user_id = 1
>     and o.id = 2;
> ```
>
> ```
> orders__id | orders__user_id | orders__status | order_details__id | order_details__order_id | order_details__amount
> ---------: | --------------: | :------------- | ----------------: | ----------------------: | --------------------:
>          2 |               1 | Ok             |                 2 |                       6 |                 20.00
>          2 |               1 | Ok             |                 2 |                       7 |                 21.00
>          2 |               1 | Ok             |                 2 |                       8 |                 22.00
>          2 |               1 | Ok             |                 2 |                       9 |                 23.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=d6e882d642d2ddb86badb07faee6b17c)*

Comment: Ну это мой верхний ответ в комменте) но он правильный)